# Which data do returned functions in python have acess to?

Tags: python, function, callback, nested, partials

Suppose we want to create a callback function which adds two numbers `arg1` and `arg2`. This could be done by returning a function reference like so:

```
def add(arg1, arg2):
   return arg1 + arg2

def partial(f, arg1, arg2):
   def wrapper():
      return f(arg1, arg2)
  
   return wrapper

callback = partial(add, 2, 4)
print(callback())

Output: 6
```

How does `wrapper` remember `arg1` and `arg2`? What do we really return with `return wrapper`? It seems like not only is part of the function code returned but also its surroundings (in this case variables defined before `wrapper`). Otherwise there would be a `NameError`.

Comment: The key word is _closure_.

Comment: Check https://zetcode.com/python/python-closures/. The code here is almost identical to yours

Answer (score 3):

Answering your main question, this happens because of something called **Closure** in python.
When you nest a function inside an enclosing function and return the nested function, the variables passed to the enclosing function are still in the scope of the nested function.

You would often see use of closures for creating decorators in python.

Comment: It’s not *just* the variables, like here.   Anything in *partial*’s `locals()`, such as a precomputed value in *partial* is visible to *wrapper*.  (though I assume it’s limited to locals *before* the `def wrapper` line)

Comment: @JLPeyret it's not limited in that way, you can have new locals _after_ the wrapped function definition that are still closed over.